How to call "unpack" on a string in ruby C-api?
I am trying to use the ruby C-api to call unpack on a ruby string.
Here is my current code:


#include "ruby.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

VALUE dangerous_func(unsigned char* buf) {
    VALUE hello_world_str;
    VALUE format_string;
    hello_world_str = rb_str_new_cstr(buf); // Create ruby string from buffer.
    format_string = rb_str_new_cstr("b8B8"); // Example format string.
    printf("Before...\n");
    rb_funcall(hello_world_str, rb_intern("unpack"), 1, format_string); // Pass the format string as argument.
    printf("After...\n");
    return Qnil; // Just return Qnil
}

// This is needed for rb_rescue
VALUE error_func(VALUE stuff) {
    return Qnil;
}

#define MAX_INPUT_SIZE 1000

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned char input[MAX_INPUT_SIZE+1]; // Input buffer
    int len;
    memset(input, 0x00, MAX_INPUT_SIZE+1); // Zero out input buffer
    ruby_setup();
    ruby_sysinit(&argc, &argv);
    RUBY_INIT_STACK;
    ruby_init();
    ruby_init_loadpath();
    len = read(0, input, MAX_INPUT_SIZE);
    rb_rescue(dangerous_func, input, error_func, Qnil); // Call the function
    ruby_finalize(); // Cleanup
    return 0;
}


After testing the code with the input aa, it just prints Before... and exits, therefore it exits in the rb_funcall function.
I looked around the ruby codebase and in the string.c file, there are many method definitions for the string object, but none of which was unpack or pack:
// ...

    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "sub", rb_str_sub, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "gsub", rb_str_gsub, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "chop", rb_str_chop, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "chomp", rb_str_chomp, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "strip", rb_str_strip, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "lstrip", rb_str_lstrip, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "rstrip", rb_str_rstrip, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "delete_prefix", rb_str_delete_prefix, 1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "delete_suffix", rb_str_delete_suffix, 1);

    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "sub!", rb_str_sub_bang, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "gsub!", rb_str_gsub_bang, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "chop!", rb_str_chop_bang, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "chomp!", rb_str_chomp_bang, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "strip!", rb_str_strip_bang, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "lstrip!", rb_str_lstrip_bang, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "rstrip!", rb_str_rstrip_bang, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "delete_prefix!", rb_str_delete_prefix_bang, 1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "delete_suffix!", rb_str_delete_suffix_bang, 1);

    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "tr", rb_str_tr, 2);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "tr_s", rb_str_tr_s, 2);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "delete", rb_str_delete, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "squeeze", rb_str_squeeze, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "count", rb_str_count, -1);

    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "tr!", rb_str_tr_bang, 2);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "tr_s!", rb_str_tr_s_bang, 2);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "delete!", rb_str_delete_bang, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "squeeze!", rb_str_squeeze_bang, -1);

    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "each_line", rb_str_each_line, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "each_byte", rb_str_each_byte, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "each_char", rb_str_each_char, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "each_codepoint", rb_str_each_codepoint, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "each_grapheme_cluster", rb_str_each_grapheme_cluster, 0);

    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "sum", rb_str_sum, -1);

    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "slice", rb_str_aref_m, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "slice!", rb_str_slice_bang, -1);

    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "partition", rb_str_partition, 1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "rpartition", rb_str_rpartition, 1);

    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "encoding", rb_obj_encoding, 0); /* in encoding.c */
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "force_encoding", rb_str_force_encoding, 1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "b", rb_str_b, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "valid_encoding?", rb_str_valid_encoding_p, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "ascii_only?", rb_str_is_ascii_only_p, 0);

    /* define UnicodeNormalize module here so that we don't have to look it up */
    mUnicodeNormalize          = rb_define_module("UnicodeNormalize");
    id_normalize               = rb_intern_const("normalize");
    id_normalized_p            = rb_intern_const("normalized?");

    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "unicode_normalize", rb_str_unicode_normalize, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "unicode_normalize!", rb_str_unicode_normalize_bang, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cString, "unicode_normalized?", rb_str_unicode_normalized_p, -1);

    rb_fs = Qnil;
    rb_define_hooked_variable("$;", &rb_fs, 0, rb_fs_setter);
    rb_define_hooked_variable("$-F", &rb_fs, 0, rb_fs_setter);
    rb_gc_register_address(&rb_fs);

    rb_cSymbol = rb_define_class("Symbol", rb_cObject);
    rb_include_module(rb_cSymbol, rb_mComparable);
    rb_undef_alloc_func(rb_cSymbol);
    rb_undef_method(CLASS_OF(rb_cSymbol), "new");
    rb_define_singleton_method(rb_cSymbol, "all_symbols", sym_all_symbols, 0);

    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "==", sym_equal, 1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "===", sym_equal, 1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "inspect", sym_inspect, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "name", rb_sym2str, 0); /* in symbol.c */
    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "to_proc", rb_sym_to_proc, 0); /* in proc.c */
    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "succ", sym_succ, 0);
    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "next", sym_succ, 0);

    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "<=>", sym_cmp, 1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "casecmp", sym_casecmp, 1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "casecmp?", sym_casecmp_p, 1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "=~", sym_match, 1);

    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "[]", sym_aref, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "slice", sym_aref, -1);
    rb_define_method(rb_cSymbol, "length", sym_length, 0);

// ...

there is also the pack.rb file:

class Array
  #  call-seq:
  #    pack(template, buffer: nil) -> string
  #
  #  Formats each element in +self+ into a binary string; returns that string.
  #  See {Packed Data}[rdoc-ref:packed_data.rdoc].
  def pack(fmt, buffer: nil)
    Primitive.pack_pack(fmt, buffer)
  end
end

class String
  # call-seq:
  #   unpack(template, offset: 0) -> array
  #
  #  Extracts data from +self+, forming objects that become the elements of a new array;
  #  returns that array.
  #  See {Packed Data}[rdoc-ref:packed_data.rdoc].
  def unpack(fmt, offset: 0)
    Primitive.pack_unpack(fmt, offset)
  end

  # call-seq:
  #   unpack1(template, offset: 0) -> object
  #
  #  Like String#unpack, but unpacks and returns only the first extracted object.
  #  See {Packed Data}[rdoc-ref:packed_data.rdoc].
  def unpack1(fmt, offset: 0)
    Primitive.pack_unpack1(fmt, offset)
  end
end



and it seems that we should call pack_unpack instead, but neither pack_unpack exists in the string method definitions. I tried to replace the unpack method with other methods and it works as intended, but when I try to use unpack, it exits before execution can get to the After... line.
So, my question is, how do I call the unpack method on a ruby string in ruby C-api?
I want the C code to be basically the same as this:
puts "Before..."
(ARGF.read).unpack("b8B8")
puts "After..."

but just in C.

While you are correct that "pack.rb" is what adds these methods to String and Array. The actual file that defines the underlying implementation is "pack.c" (Source)

@engineersmnky I mean sure, but do you know how can I call the function on the ruby string in the C-code?

Your code works okay for me (as in I get Before... and After... printed, there are a bunch of warnings generated when compiling). It looks like in your case an exception is being thrown. You should add some code to your error_func to see what is happening. Note that this function should have two parameters, the second will be the exception object being thrown.

@matt How do I get the exception text from the exception object and also how do I pass the exception object to the error_func? Edit: Also which ruby version are you using and what command do you use to compile the program?

@Somenerdwhodoesnothavea My modified version of your code, along with the command I’ve been using is at https://gist.github.com/mattwildig/e4b4d5407755867c3e2520ce84f474aa. Note I changed the format string to be an integer to force an exception to occur. I’m using Ruby 3.3.0 on a Mac.

@matt I get this error when running the binary: ruby: undefined method unpack' for an instance of String (NoMethodError). I compiled ruby 3.3.0 from source. Are you linking the shared library (the.sofile) or the static library? I compiled thesofiles instead of the static libraries and that may cause these problems. My compile command is otherwise the same, except I useclang` as the compiler instead, but that shouldn't affect things.

@matt Interestingly, if I compile with gcc, I get these errors: https://pastebin.com/gCVjndF5 , maybe that is a clue? When executing with LD_PRELOAD set to the libruby.so file, I still get that error. I also had to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH , such that the program finds the libruby.so file. I downloaded ruby 3.3.0 from here: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/

@Somenerdwhodoesnothavea I installed Ruby with https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install which gives me a static lib. I’m also using clang. Not finding the unpack method is strange, I don’t know what could be causing that. Perhaps use methods on a string, and compare to the same in a normal Ruby program.

@matt I ran the methods on the string and it seems that the unpack method isn't there for some reason. Here are some notes: https://pastebin.com/bTCAispg I am using the dynamic library, so I think that may affect things. I am going to try with ruby install and see what happens. If I try to run irb and then call "methods" on a string, the unpack method is there.

@matt Also my compile command is this: "clang -Wall -I/home/oof/.rubies/ruby-3.3.0/include/ruby-3.3.0/ -I/home/oof/.rubies/ruby-3.3.0/include/ruby-3.3.0/x86_64-linux/ -L/home/oof/.rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ test.c -lruby -lgmp -lz -o test"
